# how to use ggplot within range of values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset of about 1000 records, following is the sample of it-

```
    Var1    Freq
3   Abhay Jadhav    22
4   Abhijit Rana    8
5   Abhinav Sahu    24
6   Abhishek Chaudhary  22
7   Abhishek Dutt   7
8   Abhishek Gautam 7
9   Abhishek Mishra 13
10  Abhishek Mukherjee  23
11  Abhishek Nair   22
12  Abhishek Panigrahi  15
13  Abhishek Tiwari 21
14  Abzal Ayub  5
15  Adhiraj Banerjee    7
```

I want to plot the same within the range of Freq like (1..5 , 6..10,11...) , the number of var1 .

Like

```
1..5 => 3 Var1 Items
6...10 => 10 Var1 Items
```

Wold like to use ggplot for doing the same,

I tried to use normal plot with break but was not impressed and my intention to use ggplot only.
I am fine to use  histogram or barplot or any better option

Comment: You can use `cut` to create a categorical variable for each range (ie. `Freq.cat <- cut(Freq, c(0,5,10,15,20), include.lowest=TRUE)`) and then just use `geom_bar` to produce a barplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
df$group <- cut(df$Freq, breaks = seq(0, max(df$Freq) + 4, by = 5), include.lowest = T)
ggplot(df, aes(x = group)) + geom_bar()
```